# Using data outside the scope of then in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I am given the following task in JavaScript: Create a DataBase object with a method called getData that returns a promise. When this promise is resolved, it returns an array.

Create a second object called Data that calls on the getData method. Create a method for Data called getFirst that returns the value of the first member in the array.

If I am understanding the task, it is impossible because you can't assign values from a promise outside of a callback.

(Actually, the task is more complicated, but I am simplifying to show just the part I was having problems with.)

Here's what I have:

```
function DataBase(){
    this.getData = function(){
        var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        return Promise.resolve(data);
    }
}

function Data(d){
    this.first = null;
    that = this;
    this.getFirst = function(){
        return this.first;
    }
    this.initialize = function(){
        dataBase = new DataBase();
        dataBase.getData().then( function(theArray){   
            console.log(theArray); //works fine
            that.first = theArray[0]; //doesn't work because promise is asyncronous
        })
    }
}

d = new Data();
d.initialize();
result = d.getFirst();
console.log(result)// is null
```

Comment: `Data` is not a method, it's a constructor here.

Comment: You should ask for clarification. As given, that task is utter nonsense (and yes, you can cite me on that). Or switch your course :-)

Comment: Apologies. The actual task stated "object", not method. I have fixed my mistake in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Use a promise on your `initialize` function and return a promise from inside the initialze function too:

```
this.initialize = function(){
    dataBase = new DataBase();
    return dataBase.getData().then( function(theArray){   
        console.log(theArray); //works fine
        that.first = theArray[0]; //doesn't work because promise is asyncronous
    })
}    

d.initialize().then(function() {
    result = d.getFirst();
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tarun. You are correct. In fact, the instructions had this same exact code, but I was so caught up in wanting to initialize just once that I lost sight of the obvious solution.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you accept the answer in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct.

> Create a DataBase object with a method called getData that returns a promise. When this promise is resolved, it returns an array.
>
> Create a second method called Data that calls on the getData method. Create a method for Data called getFirst that returns the value of the first member in the array.

That is very very sloppy language. Promises don't *return* something, they *fulfill* with some value. And `getFirst` surely isn't supposed to *return* the first member itself, but *return a promise for it*.

Also it's unclear whether `Data` is supposed to be a *constructor* / class, because if so it shouldn't be called a *method*. Or if it is not, then "method for Data" is meaningless.

I would have understood the task so that the expected result is simply

```
var DataBase = {
    getData: function() {
        var array = […];
        return Promise.resolve(array);
    },
    getFirst: function() {
        return this.getData().then(function(array) { return array[0]; });
    }
};
```